# Populate the data in its own field

Tags: sql, database

How can the data be populated in its own field? See the field called 'vSoup Text'.

```
SELECT [iFormID]
  ,[iPracID]
  ,[iPatID]
  ,[vFormName]
  ,[vSoapText]
  ,[tHTML]
  ,[iUserID]
  ,[dDATE] FROM CustomForm  where iPatID = 40 and vFormName = 'Diabetes Screening'
```

[image]

I need to break the data when you see '/br'

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I've found to do this is by using a function.  You could use SSIS, but the way that I've used is using a function.

https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings